# Only allowing Uppercase characters in a text box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am working on an MVC project where in my text box I will only allow a user to enter uppercase characters.

This works in Razor when doing the following:

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new{@class="upper"}
```

I then apply the relevant code in my CSS file

However if I have the following code in Razor it doesnt work:

```
    @Html.TextBox("Name", new{@class="upper"}
```

All I get is the text box showing `{@class="upper"}`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the second parameter in the @Html.TextBox helper is for the initial value of the textbox.  if you do not want to specify an initial value you will either need to pass null or the empty string and then your attributes:

```
@Html.TextBox( "name", null, new { @class = "upper" })
```

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter is the textbox value, so you should leave it empty and put the class in the third parameter:

```
@Html.TextBox("Name", null,new{@class="upper"})
```